# ssl application data zero bytes myth

Tags: ssl, wireshark, traffic, tls1.2

Recently I analyzed several SSL/TLS application packets, and I found that rather interesting that some packets start with **fixed 7 zero bytes** in the very beginning of SSL/TLS application data packet.

[TLS 1.2 application data example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXTbJ.jpg)

[TLS 1.2 application data example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMmqY.jpg)

I don't know why this happen? Intuitively the encrypted message should by random bytes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to avoid linked images because they might disappear in the future and turn your question non understandable

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a peculiarity specific to Galois Counter Mode. What Wireshark calls the “Encrypted Application Data” is in this case a `GenericAEADCipher`, which is defined in [RFC 5246, section 6.2.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.3) and begins with:

```
opaque nonce_explicit[SecurityParameters.record_iv_length];
```

[RFC 5288, section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288#section-3) describes this field for GCM:

> Each value of the nonce_explicit MUST be distinct for each distinct
> invocation of the GCM encrypt function for any fixed key.  Failure to
> meet this uniqueness requirement can significantly degrade security.
> The nonce_explicit MAY be the 64-bit sequence number.

The nonce doesn’t need to be random, or unpredictable – but it absolutely must be unique (see also [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55667/tls-sequence-number#55676)). Using the TLS record sequence number (not the TCP sequence number!) is a good way to ensure uniqueness within one connection, and so NSS, for example, follows that recommendation (see `lib/ssl/ssl3con.c`, lines 2148-2167 and 2994-3016 in NSS 3.27.1).

So, at the start of a new TLS connection, that nonce will just be a bunch of zeroes. Note that in your second screenshot, the last byte is already `01` – presumably, that’s the second record in the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The 7 leading 0's in each SSL chunk means it's unlikely to be SSL encrypted data. There must be some obfuscation or this is just hidden data channel in SSL streams/chunks.

Comment: Still not quite clear, could you please give me a reference link or something? thanks.

Comment: Sorry don't have a reference, it's just extremely rare to have that many consecutive 0's in the output of encryption.